# Operator "<<" overloading return type

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose there is a cPoint class.

```
class cPoint {
  int x, y, z;
};
```

I wanted to print all of three variables in a single statement. So, I overloaded operator << just like

```
   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &cout, cPoint &p);

   std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, cPoint &p) {
     out << p.get_x() << " " << p.get_y() << " " << p.get_z() << std::endl;
     return out;
   }
```

Make sense?

My question lies in the lines of that what would happen in case of insertion operator(>>). I overloaded that as well to take the values of x, y and z into a single statement.

```
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &cin, Point &p);

    std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Point &p) {
        int tmp;
        in >> tmp;
        p.set_x(tmp);
        in >> tmp;
        p.set_y(tmp);
        in >> tmp;
        p.set_z(tmp);
    }
```

Clear?

```
int main() {
  cout << p << endl;
  cin >> p;
}
```

I know that if operator<< returned void then the compiler evaluates cout << p << endl;
Due to the precedence/associativity rules, it evaluates this expression as (cout << cPoint) << endl;. cout << cPoint calls our void-returning overloaded operator<< function, which returns void. Then the partially evaluated expression becomes: void << endl;, which makes no sense!

But what would happen in case of >>. Why can't I return a void for >> as like:

```
    void operator>> (std::istream &cin, Point &p);
```

Because it does not matter if cin >> p returns void or something else. There is no other operand who could use it. This is not clear.

Comment: BTW you should use `(std::ostream &out, const cPoint &p)` instead of `(std::ostream &out, cPoint &p)` - otherwise you are giving the impression that your output operator modifies its `cPoint` argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can* return `void` from stream extracting `operator >>`, just like you can return `void` from a stream inserting `operator <<`. And just like with the inserting one, it will prevent you from doing chaining:

```
cPoint p, q;
cin >> p >> q; // This would fail with return type void
```

... and the very common test-correctness idiom:

```
cPoint p;
if (cin >> p) {
}
```

Comment: Agree. But in my case, I am not doing any chaining for cin. Right?

Comment: I am doing chaining in cout statement not in cin statement.

cout << p << endl; <== Chaining
cin >> p; <== No chaining

Comment: As I said, you *can* return `void`. In your case, you're not doing any chaining, so it will work. And you're not doing any validation, which you should, and which will not work with the `void`. And the `void` will prevent anyone else from doing chaining or validation. So returning `void` is a Bad Idea(TM).

Comment: Well. This is what I wanted to hear that it should work.

When I changed:

`code friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &cin, Point &p)`; TO 
`code friend void operator>> (std::istream &cin, Point &p);`

AND
`code void operator>> (std::istream &in, Point &p) {`
    `code int tmp;`
    `code in >> tmp;`
    `code p.set_x(tmp);`
    `code in >> tmp;`
    `code p.set_y(tmp);`
    `code in >> tmp;`
    `code p.set_z(tmp);`
}

It did not even compile.

Comment: @HemantBhargava That it does not compile is information that *should have been **very explicitly** mentioned in the question.* Along with the full error message and (ideally) a [minimal reproducing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well.

Answer (score 3):

> I overloaded `operator <<` just like ...

Proper override should take the second parameter by `const` reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &cout, const cPoint &p);
//                                                   ^^^^^
```

> I overloaded that as well to take the values of x, y and z into a single statement.

You forgot to return `in` from the implementation:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Point &p) {
    int tmp;
    in >> tmp;
    p.set_x(tmp);
    in >> tmp;
    p.set_y(tmp);
    in >> tmp;
    p.set_z(tmp);
    return in; <<== Here
}
```

Making it `void` would prevent you from reading anything else after the point on the same line.